# not able to call bootstrap popup from code behind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to call bootstrap popup from code behind. This is my html

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="scripts/Jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/bootstrap-min.js"></script>
 <script>
    function openModel() {
        $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
            html: true,
            content: function() {
                return $('#popover-content').html();
            }
        });
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="OnClick" Text="sd"/>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div id="popover-content" class="hide">

        <div class="form-group"> 
          <asp:Label runat="server" id="lblDescription"></asp:Label>
        </div>

        </div>

    </div>

 </form>

</body>
```

Here is my code to call popup

```
protected void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModel();", true);
    }
```

But when i click on button nothing happens. I dont see any error in console as well. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why would you launch it from code behind anyways? Why not launch it from JavaScript on the client side?

Comment: Because there is some reason for doing from code behind. Its way easy in Js i know but cant do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ensure Your Selectors Are Correct**

It doesn't currently look like your selector for your event would target anything. The selector `$("[data-toggle=popover]")` will target an element with the `data-toggle` attribute set to "popover", however I don't see anything on your markup that would match that.

**Possible Race Condition**

Issues like this can generally be the result of a race-condition that is causing the `openModel()` function to be called prior to your other content (i.e. jQuery and Bootstrap) not being ready.

You can try resolving this by adding an explicit delay to call your function using the [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) function :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Pop", "setTimeout(function(){ openModel();},10);", true);
```

If you are still having issues, consider using the Developer Tools (F12) within your browser and checking to ensure that there are no errors present within the Console or Network tabs.

**Ensure Your References Are Correct (And In The Proper Location)**

If you do notice that your jQuery or Bootstrap libraries aren't being loaded properly, you could consider taking advantage of the [`ResolveUrl()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl(v=vs.110).aspx) method that would allow you to pass in a relative URL and it would return the absolute URL that corresponds to it :

```
<script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/scripts/Jquery-2.1.4.js") %>"></script>
<script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/scripts/bootstrap-min.js") %>"></script>
```

This can often be helpful to ensure that you retrieve the file you are looking for.

You might also consider placing your `<script>` tags near the closing `</body>` element of your markup to ensure they aren't called until all of the previous content has been loaded :

```
        <!-- Form Contents -->
    </form>
    <script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/scripts/Jquery-2.1.4.js") %>"></script>
    <script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/scripts/bootstrap-min.js") %>"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: i tried but same issue. No errors in console. i have rechecked

Comment: I've added a few other possible resolutions that could be applicable. You may want to revisit some of them.